# Service still running when the screen is locked

Tags: android, bluetooth, screen-lock

I have a connection screen where I have a search button, after I clicked it a list of discoverable devices are posted, I click on the desired device to make pair and connection with, the connection is established and when I lock the screen the connection is lost, how can I improve my code in order to have the service still working? This is how I tried to implement it, onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() are also implemented inside launchApplication().

```
 public static void launchActivity(Context context, String deviceAddress){
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mCurrentDeviceAddress = deviceAddress; //getIntent().getExtras().getString(ConnectionScreen.PREFS_DEVICE_ADDR);
    mChatService = new BluetoothMeterService(context, mHandler);
    connectDevice();
    if (mChatService != null) {
        if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothMeterService.STATE_NONE) {
            mChatService.start();
        }
    }

}


// Automatically try to connec with the known mac address;
private static class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothDevice device;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice d) {
        this.device = d;
    }

    public void run() {

        while (mConnectThread == Thread.currentThread()) {
            if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothMeterService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.e(TAG, "STATE_CONNECTED");
                break;
            } else if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothMeterService.STATE_CONNECTING) {
                try {
                    //Thread.sleep(2000);
                    Log.e(TAG, "STATE_CONNECTING");
                    mChatService.connect(device);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            } else
                try {

                    Log.e(TAG, "STATE_DISCONECTED");
                    mChatService.start();
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
        }
    }
}


// create the bluetooth device object, and try to connect with it
// consistantly and automatically.
private static void connectDevice() {
    if (mCurrentDeviceAddress == null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth MAC address is not assigned.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //context.finish();
        return;
    }
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mCurrentDeviceAddress);
    // showDialog(Dialog_Connect);
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();
}




// The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothMeterService
private static final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.e(TAG, msg.toString());
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case BluetoothMeterService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        Log.e(TAG, "handler - STATE_CONNECTED");
                        for(CustomizedBluetoothDevice device : mDeviceList){
                            if(device.getAddress() == mCurrentDeviceAddress){
                                device.setStatus(BluetoothMeterService.STATE_CONNECTED);
                            }
                        }
                        updateUI(/*mDeviceList*/);
                        // mTextViewTitle.setText("Device: " + mConnectedDeviceName);
                        // mTextViewStatus.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                        break;
                    case BluetoothMeterService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        Log.e(TAG, "handler - STATE_CONNECTING");
                        for(CustomizedBluetoothDevice device : mDeviceList){
                            if(device.getAddress() == mCurrentDeviceAddress){
                                device.setStatus(BluetoothMeterService.STATE_CONNECTING);
                            }
                        }
                        updateUI(/*mDeviceList*/);
                        // mTextViewStatus.setText(R.string.title_connecting);
                        break;
                    case BluetoothMeterService.STATE_NONE:
                        Log.e(TAG, "handler - STATE_NONE");
                        for(CustomizedBluetoothDevice device : mDeviceList){
                            if(device.getAddress() == mCurrentDeviceAddress){
                                device.setStatus(BluetoothMeterService.STATE_NONE);
                            }
                        }
                        updateUI(/*mDeviceList*/);
                        // mTextViewStatus.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);
                        break;
                    case BluetoothMeterService.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
                        Log.e(TAG, "handler - STATE_DISCONNECTING");
                        for(CustomizedBluetoothDevice device : mDeviceList){
                            if(device.getAddress() == mCurrentDeviceAddress){
                                device.setStatus(BluetoothMeterService.STATE_DISCONNECTING);
                            }
                        }
                        updateUI(/*mDeviceList*/);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                Log.e(TAG, "handler - MESSAGE_READ " + readMessage);
                // bufferMessege += readMessage;
               /* if (mMessage != null) {
                    mMessage.add(new CustomizedMessage(readMessage, true));
                    updateUI();
                }*/
                // bufferMessege = "";
                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                Log.e(TAG, "handler - MESSAGE_READ " + MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Log.e(TAG, "handler - MESSAGE_READ " + MESSAGE_TOAST);

                break;
        }
    }
};

public void stopActivity(){
    if (mChatService != null)
    {
        mChatService.stop();
        mChatService = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code written in onPause()?. Because when you lock the screen onPause life cycle method gets called.

Comment: I solved the problem, it was related on the method I called onPause(), Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually normal. As far you leave the app and the android lifecycle calls the `onDestroy()` method, all connections should go offline. Therefore you need a process which is working further on in the background. Here you can use the Android `Service` component. This will work as long you are using the resources, as soon its finished with the process the `Service` is going to close. So it depends, what you need. If you need a background service which shall work forever in the background, you should use the `startForeground()` method of `Service`.

More infomration about `Service` here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume launchActivity is called from within one of your activity's lifecycle methods.

if so - you are basically creating a background logic which is 'attached' to an activity, i.e. a UI component. 
This is a bad idea.

Why?

Because Android is rather quick in reclaiming background activities **together with threads spawned from them**, when resources run low.

What you should do is to explicitly inform Android that this logic is to be treated as background logic, i.e.
not connected to activity visibility of to screen being on.

To do that you should declare a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

In manifest:

```
<service
  android:name="MyConnectionService"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:label="@string/service_name"  >
</service>
```

And in code:

```
public class MyConnectionService extends Service {

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       // <------------ place connection logic here
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
  }
}
```

If you want your logic to execute apart from the UI thread (as I believe yo do), use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

```
public class MyConnectionService extends IntentService {

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       // <--------- run connection logic on a dedicated thread here
  }
}
```

Finally, if you want your service to always stay in the air no matter what (and most apps **do not need such behavior**), declare your service as a foreground service:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.msg_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyConnectionService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```